# How can I cure citrus leaves that have brown dots?

Tags: leaves, citrus

In the picture you can see brown dots on my indoor citrus tree. I have the citrus tree right next to a window. I also have 3 small citrus trees like this, but only this one has brown dots. I treat them all the same way.

I can remove these dots by hand.

**How should I cure citrus leaves?**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This question appears to be about the same plant as in your other one - if you have an infestation of insects (scale in particular) then grazing damage will occur on the leaves. I refer you to the answer given under the other question.